# Can i catch Volley Debug message programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-logcat

Can i catch Volley Debug message programmatically in Android?
For example : D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish:...
(From logcat debug log level)
I would like to do something when Volley send this message.

Comment: I would suggest you take a closer look at the available methods in the `Request` class and find an appropriate one to plug in your logic. I don't think trying to intercept the log messages and act on them is a good and reliable approach.

Comment: Yes that would be a nice solution but i dont get error or response from methods. (I override these methods but nothing answers from parseNetworkResponse,deliver/Reponse/Error,onErrorResponse,onResponse.)

Comment: What event are you exactly trying to intercept via the log messages?

Comment: this is a json post to backend (server). It's 1MB size (String) message to jsonObjectRequest. The server get this and handle this but nothing answer from status of my post. But when the request finished the Volley send me a that message in logcat (debug lvl)

Comment: Try and debug the `NetworkDispatcher` and the `BasicNetwork` classes from Volley to see what is exactly happening with your request. If nether `parseNetworkResponse` or `parseNetworkError` are called, there is a bug somewhere in the response handling.

Comment: how to use these classes to check my Volley status? Can you write an example please?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. You just run your app in debug and put breakpoints in the appropriate places. When you reach a breakpoint, you can control the execution of code step by step. That way you can trace what happens with your request and why you are not getting your expected result.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but finally i found a solution. :) 

 `RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener listener = new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request request) {
                //here you can do anything...
            }
        };
        requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(listener);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener listener =
new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener()
{ @Override public void onRequestFinished(Request request)
 {
  if(request.equals(yourRequest))
   {
     // what you want...
   }
 } 
}; requestQueue.addRequestFinishedListener(listener);
```